# Stream tweets of specific account\s doesn't work with Tweetinvi

Tags: c#, twitter, streaming, tweetinvi

I'm trying to use tweetinvi to follow specific users in a streaming mode.
I try to test AddFollow with my twitter account (tweet something and see if it catches that) - doesn't work (BTW - AddTrack do work)

1. How do I get my twitter user ID (is http://mytwitterid.com/ is the formal User ID from tweetinvi perspective?
2. How else can I test it - or what is wrong here?

   ```
    var filteredStream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();

       filteredStream.AddFollow(myTwitterUserId);            

       filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) =>{
        Console.WriteLine(args.Tweet.Text);};

       Thread t = new Thread(() =>
       {
           // Start the stream matching any of the conditions
           filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
       });

   t.Start();
   ```